# Faster methods than PHP FTP functions for checking if files are in public html directory

Tags: php, performance, ftp

I have around 295 domains to check if they contain files in their public_html directory's. Currently I am using the PHP FTP functions but the script takes around 10 minutes to complete. I am trying to shorten down this time, what methods could I use to achieve this.

Here is my PHP code

```
  <?php
  foreach($ftpdata as $val) {

    if (empty($val['ftp_url'])) {

        echo "<p>There is no URL provided</p>";

    }

    if (empty($val['ftp_username']))    {

        echo "<p>The site ".$val['ftp_url']." dosent have a username</p>";

    }

    if (empty($val['ftp_password']))    {

        echo "<p>The site ".$val['ftp_url']." dosent have a password</p>";

    }



    if($val['ftp_url'] != NULL && $val['ftp_password'] != NULL && $val['ftp_username'] != NULL) {

        $conn_id = @ftp_connect("ftp.".$val['ftp_url']);

        if($conn_id == false)   {

            echo "<p></br></br><span>".$val['ftp_url']." isnt live</span></p>";

        }
        else    {

            $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $val['ftp_username'], $val['ftp_password']);

            ftp_chdir($conn_id, "public_html");

            $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

            if (count($contents) > 3)   {

                echo "<p><span class='green'>".$val['ftp_url']." is live</span><p>";
            }
            else {

                echo "<p></br></br><span>".$val['ftp_url']." isnt live</span></p>";
            }
        }
    }



 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a publicly available file you can use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to try to grab it. If it is successful you know it is there. If it fails then it is not. You don't need to download the entire file. Just limit it to a small amount of characters so it's fast and not wasting bandwidth.

```
$page = file_get_contents($url, NULL, NULL, 0, 100);
if ($page !== false)
{
    // it exists
}
```

Comment: I'm not downloading any file, I'm just using FTP to traverse the directories of the sites to see if there are any files in that directory. Unless I am wrong and greatly misunderstanding something

Comment: I'm not saying to download the file. Just *try* to and if you can then you know it exists. In my example it limits the attempted download to 100 characters to make it fast since getting the file is unnecessary.

Comment: Tried that method and it takes around 6-7 minutes which is still quite slow. Probably a 1 minute improvement

Answer (score 0):

Use curl. With option CURLOPT_NOBODY set to true request method is set to HEAD and do not transfer body.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"); //for example google logo
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//get content
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// close
curl_close($ch);

//work with result
var_dump($content);
?>
```

In output if isset "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" then the file/resourse exists.

PS. Try to use curl_multi_*. It's very fast.

Comment: Tried this and it takes 7 minutes or so. Which isnt fast enough. Not sure about curl_multi as the results im using are run through a loop.

Comment: curl_multy_* make all request in parallel. It's faster then sequence.

Answer (score 0):

M, this is really just an explanation of [AlexeyKa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279064/alexeyka)'s answer.  The reason for your scan talking 10 minutes is that you are serialising some 300 network transactions, each of which is taking roughly 2 seconds on average, and 300 x 2s gives you your total 10min elapsed time.

The various approaches such as requesting a header and no body can trim the per-transaction cost but the killer is that you are still running your queries one at a time.   What the **curl_multi_*** routines allow you do you is to run batches in parallel, say 30 x batches of 10 taking closer to 30s.  Scanning through the PHP documentation's user contributed notes give this post which explains how to set this up:
[Executing multiple curl requests in parallel with PHP and curl_multi_exec](http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2008/02/curl_multi_exec/).

The other option (if you are using **php-cli**) is simply to kick off, say, ten batch threads each one much as your current code, but with its own sublist of one tenth of the sites to check.

Since either approach is largely latency bound rather specific link capacity-bound, the time should fall largely by the same factor.